# Wrong word count in page_content.count (PyPDF2)

Tags: python, pypdf

I wrote the following code in Python to count keywords in a pdf file, yet the word count differs from that of web browsers. Hereunder, the code is used to count instances of the word "Windows" in the Microsoft's 10-Q report of April 2020 (retrieved from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Investor/sec-filings.aspx)

```
import PyPDF2
filepath = "Microsoft - 10-Q.pdf"
pdf_file = open(filepath, 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
total_number_of_keywords = 0
for page in range(number_of_pages):
    read_page = read_pdf.getPage(page)
    page_content = read_page.extractText()
    counted_keywords_per_page = page_content.count('windows')
    total_number_of_keywords += counted_keywords_per_page
print(total_number_of_keywords)
```

The code outputs 0 as the number of times "windows" was mentioned. Yet, both Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome retrieve 60 instances of the word "windows".

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The 'page_content' is empty. This is [an open issue PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/168)

You can use another PDF processor package, like [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/) (using import of the `fitz` module):

```
import re
import fitz

filepath = "Microsoft - 10-Q.pdf"
pdf_file = fitz.open(filepath)
pdf_pages = pdf_file.pageCount

full_text = []
for page in pdf_file.pages(0,pdf_pages,1):
    text = str(page.getText())
    full_text.append(text)
full_text = "".join(full_text)
print (len(re.findall('Windows', full_text)))
```

Comment: Would you have a suggestion of other PDF to text converters in Python? I would like to count keywords of a batch of files at once.

Comment: There are a lot of packages for pdf to text conversion. The one I like to use is PyMuPDF: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Git Repo: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF

Edit to answer: Added code using PyMuPDF.